# Photoshop CS 4 - Gradient overlay

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In CS4 if I drag the text tool to make a text box, add my text then apply the gradient overlay effect it starts from the top sentence all the way to the bottom sentence. Is there a way to have the effect be applied to every line?

Comment: Maybe this is a little obvious, but you could type up each line as a separate text layer and apply the gradient to each.

Comment: yea but then you can't apply paragraph effects. You could take it one step further and just shift select the text and apply the effect to each row of text on one layer. I'm just wondering if there is a way not work arounds.